# Straight Braces

Tags: symbols, braces, stacking-symbols

Can I make a variant of Latex Braces? In some equations system, I'd like to use a left brace like in this picture:

[image: Straight brace with v-shape in the middle but without curves at either end]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: The larger braces are built with specifications hardwired in the `cmex10.tfm` file. Building a virtual font that has only the necessary bits seems the way to go, but it's not what I'd call easy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Prepare the following file and call it `scmex10.vpl`

```
(FAMILY SCMEX)
(FACE O 352)
(CODINGSCHEME TEX MATH EXTENSION)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 37254272422)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.0)
   (STRETCH R 0.0)
   (SHRINK R 0.0)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.430555)
   (QUAD R 1.000003)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.0)
   (DEFAULTRULETHICKNESS R 0.039999)
   (BIGOPSPACING1 R 0.111112)
   (BIGOPSPACING2 R 0.166667)
   (BIGOPSPACING3 R 0.2)
   (BIGOPSPACING4 R 0.6)
   (BIGOPSPACING5 R 0.1)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME cmex10)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(CHARACTER O 70
   (CHARWD R 0.888891)
   (CHARDP R 0.900009)
   (VARCHAR
      (TOP O 76)
      (MID O 74)
      (BOT O 76)
      (REP O 76)
      )
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 70)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 74
   (CHARWD R 0.888891)
   (CHARDP R 1.800018)
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 74)
      )
   )
(CHARACTER O 76
   (CHARWD R 0.888891)
   (CHARDP R 0.300003)
   (VARCHAR
      (REP O 76)
      )
   (MAP
      (SETCHAR O 76)
      )
   )
```

Run the following shell command

```
vptovf scmex10.vpl
```

In the working directory you'll find the files `scmex10.tfm` and `scmex10.vf`. In the same working directory prepare the following LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{scmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{scmex}{m}{n}{<->sfixed*scmex10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{straightbrace}{OMX}{scmex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\straightbrace}{\mathopen}{straightbrace}{'70}{straightbrace}{'70}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\straightbrace
\begin{array}{@{\,}l}
a = 1\\
b = 2\\
c = 3\\
d = 4\\
e = 5
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you really like it, then place the `scmex10.tfm` and `scmex10.vf` files in the proper place of your local TeX tree, and enjoy them. You might want to make a small `.sty` file out of the four `\Declare...` lines.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your example works fine here.
I have changed some other math symbols, and when I try to put this code on my existung code, I get an error:
Latex error: No room for a new \mathgroup .

Can I use three or more Math FontFamily?

Comment: @user13596 Use as few math fonts as possible. You can add to the scmex10 font, if you're so daring.

Comment: How can I add to the scmex10?

Comment: @user13596 Along the same scheme; but a course in PL format would be quite long. With `texdoc vptovf` you can look at the allowed instructions.